# Cordova 2.1.0 (PhoneGap) create script for Android says "Project already exists" or "An error occurred. Deleting project"

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create an Android project on **Windows** using Cordova 2.2.0 (PhoneGap). According to this [blog post](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html) this command should work -

```
create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>
```

But I am getting a message "Project already exists!". I have used the same PC to create, package and submit an Android app so I know I have Java, Javac, Ant, Android e.t.c. installed.

I have also tried this on a Mac with Cordova 2.1.0 and there I get the message "An error occurred. Deleting project.."

Could you please suggest what might be the cause of this error and a possible fix?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This problem seems to be fixed in Cordova 2.2.0 but I haven't found a workaround for 2.1.0

Comment: What happens when you specify a different project folder?

Comment: @vodich I will use Eclipse to build and package the app once I get the project generated - is that what you mean?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I get the same problem. When I use a relative path (e.g. "../") it says "Could not retrieve the commons-codec. Please download it yourself and put into the framework/libs directory. This process may fail now. Sorry. C:\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-android\bin\create.js(97,7) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'NameSpace(...)' is null or not an object"

Comment: You have phonegap plugin for eclipse, I think it is much easier to create new Android phonegap project in eclipse since you will use it later to package app

Comment: @vodich ok - that's true. It defeats the purpose this setup script but I guess that's a work around :-)

Comment: Weird, it is having problems getting the commons codec package. It may be possible that the script is looking for codec version 1.6 which has probably been deleted off the website. Open create.js and see, you may need it to be switched to 1.7.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It is looking for the 1.6 codec. *create.bat line:96

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To be clear, your target project path should be to be where you want the project to be created and then the last directory will be *what* you want to be created. For example:

```
./create ./test2 com.mytest MyTest
```

In this case you want to create a project in the current directory in a new folder called "test2" and this folder has not been created yet (it will be created when this is run).

**UPDATE:** If you are using a newer verison of the Cordova Edge or greater, i highly recommend using the Cordova CLI Utility here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: What OS are you using? I think my problem is related to Windows. I get this error when I use a relative path  "Could not retrieve the commons-codec. Please download it yourself and put into the framework/libs directory. This process may fail now. Sorry. C:\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-android\bin\create.js(97,7) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'NameSpace(...)' is null or not an object"

Comment: I am on OSX. Seems like you may be missing some of the Apache libs. I know on OSX apache server comes pre-installed so may be why I never experienced this. Did you instal the commons-codec? You can get it here: http://commons.apache.org/codec/

Comment: that worked. Thanks! I think it's worth adding that to your answer. I just downloaded the codec and put it in the folder incubator-cordova-android/frameworks/lib (codec download: http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi). Sometimes it shows the error message but still creates the project - odd (o_O)

Comment: I have added your comment about the codec libs to your answer. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 36):

This drove me up the wall. Solution. Do not create the folder for the project. It will create one for you.

```
create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>
```

When specifying `<project_folder_path>`, do **NOT** first create the folder on your HD.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Guh, I remember the good 'ol days when the phonegap walkthrough wasn't quite so (ahem) 'helpful'.

Answer (score 5):

A few things to check to help solve this problem:

- **Did you download the correct version of PhoneGap from the correct LOCATION?** It appears as if there are versions of PhoneGap that do not come packaged with `Cordova-2.x.0.jar`, which is necessary to run the script. [Download here](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/#download) to obtain PhoneGap with the correct JAR file.
- **Did you already create the folder?** The documentation claims that you can use this command as long as the new folder is blank. *This is not true*. **Make sure the folder does not exist before attempting to create the project.**
- **Do you have the latest version of Ant?** You will need Ant 1.8.0 or greater to run PhoneGap with Android. Use `ant -v` to verify your version.
- **Is your .bash_profile/Environment Varibles PATH set properly?** [The official documentation has been updated to reflect this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android_3a_setup_your_path_environment_variable_on_mac_os), but you will absolutely need these variables set correctly in order to create the project.
- **Did you update the terminal to reflect your new PATHs?** `source .bash_profile` or `. .bash_profile` in your currently open terminal window so your paths are updated when running the `create` command.
- **Do you have the correct commons-codec?** You may receive an accompanying error referring to a missing `commons-codec` file, which you can download [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/commons-codec-1.6-bin.zip).

Between all of those, you should be able to get an Android project up and running with PhoneGap 2.1.0 or greater.

Comment: thanks @acconrad that's a great checklist. I think in my case it was a combination of #2 and #6

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you haven't given the folder path of an existing folder. Delete the folder if it exist already.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I tried this when I used the C:\ drive as my destination e.g. create "C:\" PackageName project-name and getting "Project already exists"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I was running the command from this location

```
Harddriv:\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-android >create "Harddriv:\externalapps\phonegap_projects\HelloWorld\" com.phonegapaapp.helloworld helloworl
```

The I got the error you mentioned.  Then instead i tried relative path to the location as follows

```
Harddriv:\cordova-2.1.0\incubator-cordova-android >create "..\externalapps\phonegap_projects" com.phonegapaapp.helloworld helloworl
```

It worked for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using:

```
create "c:\yada\yada\pic to post" <package_name> <project_name>
```

but when i took the spaces out the folder name it worked

```
create "c:\yada\yada\pictopost" <package_name> <project_name>
```

So if you have spaces in the project path then take them out.

Comment: I am using this format on Windows -

    create "C:\" PackageName project-name

and getting "Project already exists"

Comment: What is driving me batty is that even when I make it "PackageName2" (add the number at the end) I get the same result (How?). :(

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
export PATH=/android-sdks/tools/:$PATH
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error:

- *Project already exists!*
  followed by:
- *An error occurred. Deleting project...*

I figured out it is important to use the valid set of characters for package and project names. Specifically:

- *package_name* allows `a-z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore)
- *project_name* allows `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore)

My *project_name* was `Test-Project`, with a dash for example.

Answer (score 0):

To any lost souls who have worked their way through these answers (as I have) and still have had no satisfaction, despite having everything configured correctly.

Try downloading phonegap from Github repo, currently version 2.3.0

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a silimar problem here, the script did't want to create my projects, I have set up all PATHS, downloaded all SDKs and tools, removed spaces - still not working.

The problem was, that the script didn't create the project sub directories.
An updated/fixed script can be found in this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/7wOqriD4YjY

or downloaded directly here:

https://phonegap.googlegroups.com/attach/b2d05c8a6a929569/create.js?view=1&part=4

Greetings!

Asped

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same experience with Windows while creating new PhoneGap project. Then I tried with relative path. For my case I wanted to create project under **C:\phonegap_projects\** parent folder and my PhoneGap bin was under **C:\phonegap\cordova-2.7.0\android\** parent folder. So I tried with, after navigating to C:\phonegap\cordova-2.7.0\android\bin directory:

```
create ..\..\..\..\phonegap_projects\<name_of_project> <package_name> <name_of_project>
```

This worked for me.