# Error on creating new Cordova2.2/android/phonegap project via cmd

Tags: cordova

Hi I'm trying my best to setup phonegap/cordova 2.2 and get the following error when running "create"

```
C:\cordova-2.2.0\incubator-cordova-android\bin>create
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
```

(i know there are no parameters added but it's the same msg no matter what)

I have the environment variables set as:

**ANDROID_HOME**
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

**ANT_HOME**
C:\Program Files\ANT\apache-ant-1.8.4

**JAVA_HOME** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09

but I just cant seem to make it do anything!

Any help is much appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 1):

Did your set your path correctly?

I had to make sure *platform-tools* and *tools* from Android were in the path as well as the *bin* folders from the Ant and Java home folders.

Also, if you're following the current version of the Getting Started With Android guide here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

I had to use the actual "PhoneGap" package (this: http://phonegap.com/download#) vs the "Cordova" one the guide linked to.

Answer (score 1):

[I previously answered this question in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650568/535467), but be sure to check for things like setting your PATH variables correctly, updating the terminal with your new `.bash_profile` file and having the latest version of ANT.