# Can't create a new Android project with PhoneGap 2.2

Tags: android, windows, cordova, sdk

I have a problem when I try to create an android project with PhoneGap. (I have windows 8 64 bit).

I put the right paths in my `PATH` environment variables, but when I try to create a new project, this is what I get:

> Cscript not found as an internal or external command... (bad translation from French but you get the point.)

This error is new to me, because before it always returned:

> Missing one of the following ...

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Though you may have the right PATH variables, you might not have the latest version of ANT or missing the `commons-codec`. [I answered this question in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650568/535467), so you might want to take a look there and see if any of those apply.