# cordova-android ./create $( which android ) exited with a 1

Tags: android, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

After executing the command to create a project...

```
./create <PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIR> <COM_PATH> <PROJECT_NAME>
```

I get the error message:

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

Troubleshooting responses:
(acconrad provided a smart checklist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475687/cordova-2-1-0-phonegap-create-script-for-android-says-project-already-exists) for solving Cordova errors...)

> Did you download the correct version of PhoneGap from the correct LOCATION? It appears as if 
>   there are versions of PhoneGap that do not come packaged with
>   Cordova-2.x.0.jar, which is necessary to run the script. Download here
>   to obtain PhoneGap with the correct JAR file.

I have followed the instructions at the [official Apache Cordova API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) site and downloaded the [cordova-android repository from github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android). The official documentation does not say anything about this jar file and as such I have not executed it.

> Did you already create the folder? The documentation claims that you
>   can use this command as long as the new folder is blank. This is not
>   true. Make sure the folder does not exist before attempting to create
>   the project.

Fresh folder path, never created.

> Do you have the latest version of Ant? You will need Ant 1.8.0 or
>   greater to run PhoneGap with Android. Use ant -v to verify your
>   version.

Ant version 1.8.2, although running the -v flag pops up the following output...

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 3 2011
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

...as if it was trying to build. I assume -v means verbose and `ant` is trying to build the current director, in which there is no build.xml file, because I'm not building a project with ant, merely finding the version, which is 1.8.2.

> Is your .bash_profile/Environment Varibles PATH set properly? The
>   official documentation has been updated to reflect this, but you will
>   absolutely need these variables set correctly in order to create the
>   project.

Both SDK paths have been set & `source`d.

> Did you update the terminal to reflect your new PATHs? source
>   .bash_profile or . .bash_profile in your currently open terminal
>   window so your paths are updated when running the create command.

Haven't restarted but $PATH outputs the correct android-sdk-macosx paths (platform-tools && tools).

> Do you have the correct commons-codec? You may receive an accompanying
>   error referring to a missing commons-codec file, which you can
>   download here.

No `commons-codec` accompanying error is being displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was indeed the PATH variables...

`/PATH/TO/android-sdk-maxosx/platform-tools`

`/PATH/TO/android-sdk-maxosx/tools`

removed the macosx from the path name.

Correcting these environment variables in ~/.bash_profile solved this problem.

Comment: you mean it was a typo in your path variable?

Comment: yup. i think the docs might have been a bit misleading/incorrect/or perhaps it was a build script which made the error. probably should have notified the docs maintainer; but, i can't exactly what caused the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

You should modifying the PATH Environment Variable:

**For Ubuntu:**
$ nano ~/.bashrc

You will now have the Nano text editor enabled on the terminal. Now, at the very top of the file, enter the following:

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK

**For Mac OS:**

look in your home directory for .bash_profile. Create the .bash_profile file if you don't have one.
Look for the PATH environment variable and add the full path to the tools/ directory to the PATH. If you don't see a line setting the PATH, you can add one: export PATH=${PATH}:/tools

https://sites.google.com/site/richgossweiler/home/android-development-notes/installing-the-android-sdk-on-the-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if the name of the COM_PATH contains an invalid character or does not have 3 namespaces like:

com.example.project

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a wrong PATH. You should edit environment variables in ~/.bash_profile.
Refer this [Blog post](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/an-unexpected-error-occurred.html)  for a detailed explanation.