# Error creating Cordova 2.2.0 project for Android with Eclipse on OS X

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cordova

I'm creating a PhoneGap project for Android on OS X, and have installed all the prerequisites. When creating the app from the terminal of PhoneGap, it is showing me the error:

> Project Already Exist. Delete and recreate.

...but there is no other project.

My terminal command for creating the app is:

```
:bin user $ ./create /user/documents/workspace/AndriodProject com.test.AndriodProject TestAndriod
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: phonegap for andriod version in iOS ? :). It should be OS X !

Comment: are you sure you use a proper path? `/user/documents/` is not a valid path on OSX, if you meant your home.

Comment: @Whizkid747 yes it is os X in mac

Comment: @VladStirbu i had just drag the folder to the terminal it takes the same path automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First check, if the folder /workspace/AndroidProject already exist - you need a new path: Phonegap should create that folder.
- I work with eclipse and I got that error, when the project-name was already used in another eclipse-project.
- Maybe your problem can be solved with the answers of question: [cordova-android ./create $( which android ) exited with a 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767007/cordova-android-create-which-android-exited-with-a-1)

Answer (score -1):

Insteasd of:

```
:bin user $ ./create /user/documents/workspace/AndriodProject com.test.AndriodProject TestAndriod
```

Use:

```
:bin user $ ./create **/user/documents/workspace/AndriodProject/TestAndriod** com.test.AndriodProject TestAndriod
```