# Trouble with getting started on PhoneGap: Apache Cordova error

Tags: android, cordova

I've been following the [PhoneGap Getting Started Guide for Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).  I'm on the step where it says: `Type in ./create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name> then press "Enter"`

However, whenever I do this command in the form of `./create ./test2 com.mytest MyTest` I get this error: `An error occurred. Deleting project...`

I'm in the right directory, and I don't believe I've done anything out of the ordinary in following their steps.

PS I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5

**Update**: I tried installing the [phonegap-master](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap) zip directly as one of the answers suggested.  Now I get a new error when I run the command in that android bin directory: `An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1`

Comment: R u trying it on windows ? try create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>

Comment: Forgot to mention i'm on mac os x

Comment: What's the output of "which android"?

Answer (score 2):

Try

> ./create ./test2/MyTest com.mytest MyTest

the project_folder_path should be a non-exist folder

Comment: forks for me! the problem was in using invalid symbols in package name

Answer (score 2):

My problem is the incorrect paths to Android SDK. If you follow the instructions straight up, it will tell you to add

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

to .bash_profile or .profile. I had to change mine to

```
export PATH=/Users/my_username/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/my_username/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
```

Comment: this worked for me to fix the error mentioned at the bottom of the original question: An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me a little bit sloppy with setting up  `PATH` right away after installation but move from a case to case-sitation notice Phongap's documenation requires `/platform-tools` and `/tools` to be included!

In my case only `/platform-tools` was included and developing worked fine as well as bash access to `adb` however the `android` executable is located in `/tools` so unless you include it `which android` will return not match.

To realise this @Nverba's link to github was very helpful as I finally stumbled across [the source for `create`script:](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/blob/masater/bin/create)

And searching for "An unexpected [...]" brought up this piece of error handling:

```
function on_error {
    echo "An unexpected error occurred: $previous_command exited with $?"
    echo "Deleting project..."
    [ -d "$PROJECT_PATH" ] && rm -rf "$PROJECT_PATH"
    exit "$?"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue despite having everything set up correctly.

I ended up downloading the Phonegap zip from Github, which has recently been bumped to version 2.3.0

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap

Using

```
./create ./my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

worked like a charm...

Hope this helps, there are about half a dozed other things that can cause this error, but they have been covered in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650568/902551).

Comment: K, now I get a new error: `An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1`

Answer (score 0):

you should navigate to the folder that contain the create first, it will be in the "phonegap(that u downloaded from [the site](http://phonegap.com/download#))/lib/android/bin"

for example: (on mac)

> cd /Users/user_name/Desktop/phonegap/lib/android/bin/

or: (on windows)

> cd C:/users/user_name/Desktop/phonegap/lib/android/bin/

then u can complete the code

> ./create ./test2/MyTest com.mytest MyTest

that's will fix your problem.

Comment: i am in that folder. and it doesn't work: `$ pwd
/Users/me/sources/phonegap stuff/cordova-2.2.0/incubator-cordova-android/bin`

Comment: can u please show provide me the link to the destination project and the link to Cordova

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue following this [getting start guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android). After tearing my hair out for hours I followed this [getting started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) which I think is older but worked.

Another thing is that the first getting started guide tells you to download [Cordova here](http://cordova.apache.org/#download) and so I was trying to do everything with that download.

Instead download the PhoneGap package from [here](http://phonegap.com/download/) and from within there you will find the Cordova js and jar files aswell as the xml folder you'll need to create your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a wrong PATH. You should edit your PATH variable.
Refer this [blog post](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/an-unexpected-error-occurred.html) for solution.