# Project wasn't created

Tags: android, cordova

I struggled through hours of getting ant and java running and now i can finally use the create command, and it runs without an error, but then no project is created in the specified folder.

What could be my problem?

[image: the command line]

Comment: Did you look in `C:\Android`? You didn't put quotes around the path.

Comment: retried with quotes and it said project already exists

Comment: Did you try with a new project name? (After adding quotes.)

Comment: yes. should the project name and package name not be in quotes? and the package name can be anything im assuming?

Comment: it's saying project already exists regardless of directory, package name and project name

Comment: The package name has to be at least two tokens (`com.example` for example; but don't use that one). There should be a command to delete a project, but I don't have the PhoneGap lib handy to see what it might be. You'll have to do a little trial-and-error with removing and re-adding PhoneGap projects.

Comment: Tried:  create 'C:\Android SDK\workspace\test1' com.hudson.pkg com.hudson.prj and it said project already exists

Comment: figured it out. the instructions did not provide ample naming instructions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475687/cordova-2-1-0-phonegap-create-script-for-android-says-project-already-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cordova 2.1.0 (PhoneGap) create script for Android says "Project already exists" or "An error occurred. Deleting project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475687/cordova-2-1-0-phonegap-create-script-for-android-says-project-already-exists)

First solution listed here.

Command should be in the following format:

```
create ./test2 com.mytest MyTest
```