# Phonegap can't create on windows

Tags: windows, cordova

I run in the phonegap android bin folder:

```
$ ./create "C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\build\MyApp\android" coza.example.myapp MyApp
```

It gives me this error:

> ./create: line 68: conditional binary operator expected

which is the first conditional in this section:

```
function replace {
    local pattern=$1
    local filename=$2
    # Mac OS X requires -i argument
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ "darwin" ]]
    then
        /usr/bin/sed -i '' -e $pattern "$filename"
    elif [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ "linux" ]]
    then
        /bin/sed -i -e $pattern "$filename"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tjorriemorrie, please let us know the solution if you managed to get this solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem *might* be because you are including quotes around the `<project_folder_path>`.  Try without the quotes.  If that doesn't work, make sure that `<project_folder_path>` does not exist first.

Then finally if it still doesn't work... try this checklist found on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650568/1775295