# Project already exists! Delete and recreate phoneGap for Mac

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Terminal give me this erorr:
    Project already exists! Delete and recreate

So What I did for take this erorr:

I Install Plagin sdk. So android working but.I am Trying to work with phoneGap.
so I did what is writing on PhoneGap.com

in terminal

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

.Bash_Profile

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/administrator/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/administrator/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools


source ~/.bash_profile
```

and from terminal:

```
cd /Users/administrator/Desktop/phonegap-2.9.0/lib/android/bin

./create /Users/administrator/Desktop/WorkHere com.andro.tut tutPG
```

and terminal show me:

```
Project already exists! Delete and recreate
```

I need Help !!! Thanks!

Comment: Answer I found:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475687/cordova-2-1-0-phonegap-create-script-for-android-says-project-already-exists



./create ./test2 com.mytest MyTest